# Quartz.Net Not Persisting Daily Time Interval

Tags: c#, sqlite, quartz.net

I have noticed the Quartz.Net does not persist all trigger types to the data base. For example the CRON trigger gets persisted while the Daily Interval does not. Is there a setting to allow persisting all trigger types to the database?

```
var props = new NameValueCollection
{
    {"quartz.jobStore.type", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" },
    {"quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz"},
    {"quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "true"},
    {"quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "default"},
    {"quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", "QRTZ_"},
    {"quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SQLiteDelegate, Quartz"},
    {"quartz.dataSource.default.provider", "SQLite"},
    {"quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString", "Data Source=MyDBFile.db;Version=3;Foreign Keys=ON;"},
    {"quartz.serializer.type", "json"},
    {"quartz.scheduler.typeLoadHelper.type" , MyTypeLoadHelper },
    {"quartz.plugin.recentHistory.type", "Quartz.Plugins.RecentHistory.ExecutionHistoryPlugin, Quartz.Plugins.RecentHistory" },
    {"quartz.plugin.recentHistory.storeType", "Quartz.Plugins.RecentHistory.Impl.InProcExecutionHistoryStore, Quartz.Plugins.RecentHistory" },
    {"quartz.serializer.type", "MySerializerType" }
};

services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory>(new StdSchedulerFactory(props));
```

**UPDATE**

If you stop Quartz from processing then Daily Interval is saved to the DB. However, once the repeat interval is done once it will delete it from the db, even though it is scheduled to run on multiple days.